# What is wrong with this circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, relay, control, automotive

This is a circuit of a vehicle ECU. It should turn on the ECU but there are some mistakes and the ECU won't turn on but I can't figure it out:

[image: image of the circuit]

Comment: What are you trying to do? What ECU?

Comment: Can you better define the ECU module and it's drive capabilities and the relay parameters?

Comment: What’s an ecu? And it’s probably a good thing that it doesn’t work.. you’re about to short your 12V battery to ground.

Answer (score 5):

a) There is no power to the coil (and there should be). All I see is a resistor labeled "ECU", but an ECU and a resistor are not the same thing.

b) There is power across the contacts (and there shouldn't be). You should have a load in series with the relay contacts. As you have it, when the contacts close, it will short out the 12 V supply.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a typical relay circuit driven by a controller:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU4fKq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A controller (or ECU) output port pin (P1), is usually not strong enough to drive a relay's solenoid on it's own, so a transistor (Q1), can be used to increase the current as required. R1 limits the current drawn from the controller when the port pin is high, R2 ensures that the transistor will be off when P1 is low. D1 reduces any flyback spikes from the relay solenoid when switching off. The contact pins from the relay go to the circuit you want to control.

Note 1:
In some cases an ECU (for e.g. in automotive applications) may have a CPU controller and the high current driver circuitry combined into one unit, (see boxed in area).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are referring to powering up the ECU when the ignition switch is turned on.

Here's the correct schematic.

[image]

However, a 'power hold' relay would also be required to keep the ECU powered up, after the ignition / engine is turned off, to allow it to run fans and other functions for an additional period of time.

Here's the complete schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.There is no power net available
2.MCU cant able to drive the Coil ,Coil required more current but MCU GPIO usually have 20 mA at Max